# Symfony FosUserBundle: Custom User Profile Form makes user registration not work

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have extended the ProfileFormType form in order to update an existing user profile:

```
namespace AppUserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class UserProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name',TextType::class,array('label'=>'profile.first_name','required' => false));
        $builder->add('surname',TextType::class,array('label'=>'profile.surnname','required' => false));
        $builder->add('email',TextType::class,['required' => false]);
        $builder->add('description',TextareaType::class,['required' => false]);

    }


    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_profile';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I perform the registration by performing an http post to `register` I get the following error message twice:

> Please enter your name.

Do you have any Idea why that happens and ho I will solve it?

### Edit 1

My Entity is:

```
namespace AppUserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userImage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The surname is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The surname is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=1024, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function setUserImage($imagepath)
    {
        $this->userImage=$imagepath;
    }

    public function functiongetUserImage()
    {
        return $this->userImage;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name=strip_tags($name);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname=strip_tags($surname);
    }

    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description=$description;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear if on submit the field is filled or not but maybe in your Entity the `name` property have some constraint like `@Assert\NotNull` o `@Assert\NotBlank`?

Comment: Yes it was just right thanks pal!

Comment: Yes I think this is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field is not empty (*on form submit*) you should check if in your Entity you've assigned some constraint to the `name` property like in the example below (*using annotation*):

- `@Assert\NotNull`
- `@Assert\NotBlank`.